# Out of Box Workflow is not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, 2016, out-of-the-box

In SharePoint 2016 , whenever any user try to initiate an out of box workflow on a specific site , all the users are getting access denied error .
It is happening on specific days i.e. on Every Monday and it gets automatically solved after 6 PM Monday .

Can any one tell me why this is happening and how I can solve it. We have checked log files and event viewer but didn't get anything specific to issue .

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try turning on "workflows can use app permissions" and there are instructions on TechNet on how to set it up